# update git hook is not echoing when i thought it should?

Tags: git

In my local gitup repo, i set up 2 variables and an echo statement

```
git config --local --add hooks.allowdeletebranch true
git config --local --add hooks.denycreatebranch false
```

and then in the local repo update my hook to: *.git/hooks/update*

After setting this, I went into the file and for the case statement section of code, I found the comment for *branch* and *delete branch*, copied below

```
        refs/heads/*,commit)
            # branch
            if [ "$oldrev" = "$zero" -a "$denycreatebranch" = "true" ]; then
                    echo "*** Creating a branch is not allowed in this repository" >&2
                    exit 1
            fi
            echo "Creating Jenkins Job for Branch."
            ;;
        refs/heads/*,delete)
            # delete branch
            if [ "$allowdeletebranch" != "true" ]; then
                    echo "*** Deleting a branch is not allowed in this repository" >&2
                    exit 1
            fi
            echo "Deleting Jenkins Job for Branch."
            ;;
```

You see 2 echo statements I added:

```
echo "Creating Jenkins Job for Branch"
echo "Deleting Jenkins Job for Branch"
```

It seems that everything is now in place, but when I create a new branch locally and set upstream, I would think i would see an echo statement, but I dont.  I also did a first commit and push as well.

I was thinking that this modification to .git might not actually be firing because the hook is not set up on the server?  If that is the case, cant i just add .git/hooks/update to my tracking such that the server then has a copy of it?

Comment: Why would you think you would?  The update hook runs (once per branch) when receiving a push.  Creating a local branch and setting the local configuration up for tracking does not cause a push.

Comment: Even editing a file, committing it, and then pushing it, I didnt see any sort of echo either.  I thought the server would push this echo / notification to me, no?  I am trying to test and confirm the echo are firing when they should (as i have not added hooks before), before swapping it out for for some python scripts

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger this is added to my local repo changes under .git/, are those preserved automatically in the server, or is there maybe a disconnect with the server configuration vs my local configuration?

Comment: Hooks are not shared between repos.  If you've put them in your local repo's `.git` folder, then they will fire when your local repo receives a push.

Comment: Ah, so my scripts could be in the repo and committed, say in a scripts folder, but I would need to edit the update file on the my server to reference this script (in the scripts folder) accordingly?

Comment: You can share the script in the repo if you want.  I don't recommend referencing repo content from the hooks directory,  (1) It might be tricky to set up (e.g. since the server is typically a bare repo), and (2) if you did set it up, it would be a gaping security hole.  Instead as part of the server-side setup you'd want to copy the verified script content into the hooks directory (or another location where not just anyone can write to it).

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger it seems that using Bitbucket as our CMS for our Git Repo is a huge limiting factor.  It wont let me access hooks directly.  I might talk to someone to see if I can get access to the server in order to leverage this.  Do you have any tricks?

Comment: I don't know about bitbucket, though it's no surprise if it limits how you work with hooks.  Perhaps someone with more bitbucket knowledge will come along, or at least maybe you have a more useful understanding of the question you need to research...

Comment: Generally though, without the mention of the bitbucket, you actually answered my question.  When dealing with git, a user needs to change the hooks on the root server and not the local copy which would then run the scripts.  Update script would run when someone creates a new branch, but for my use case, I was doing it in my local version, not the server version.  I shall make a new question once i narrow down a new question.